# Test Cases of Robot Framework are getting failed on server giving error "TypeError: get_request() got an unexpected keyword argument"

Tags: testing, robotframework

I have a project in Java and the test scripts are written in robot.
I want to run my test scripts on the server where I have a WAR file, (after building), of my project. When I am running my test scripts on the local system it working, but When I run my test scripts on server, some tests are getting passed and some are getting failed. My server is Ubuntu 14.04.

I am using the following command to run test scripts on server:

```
pybot -v env:dev /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AnATest/tests/
```

where env:dev is just environment name and /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/AnATest/tests/
is my directory where all my robot tests files are residing.

Please tell me, if more information is required.

Comment: How are they failing? Are you getting errors? What errors?

Comment: Actually, I have 32 test scripts out of which only 4 are getting passed and remaining are getting failed on server, whereas in local system every test scripts are passed. Yes, I am getting errors saying that "TypeError: get_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'SomeService/au/tokens/sso?realm' ".

Comment: Just a bit of cleanup and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you simply have a different version of a library on your server than on your local machine. The one on the server has a `get request` keyword that doesn't take the same arguments as the one on your local machine.

Comment: Yes, after adding request library, for both python and robot, it is working.